# com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase object handling

Tags: mongodb

From mongo documentation, its clear that we need to have one mongoClient per application.

However, there is no mention if we can re-use same mongodatabase object which we get from mongoclient

MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("mongoDbName");

In my current application, i have cached this object (db) and not seen issues so far while performing read and write operations. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no such issue in this case. Typical practice is that "database" and "collection" handles get re-instantiated more frequently based of a "connection" that is "passed around". There is nothing wrong with "passing around" those values as well, but there is also no specific advantage in caching such things, as these operations actually have no I/O and are just internal assignments. You may as well be caching `1+1` to put it in plain terms. But it really does not matter.

Comment: Thanks Neil, this helps.